# How to parse specific date format with strptime?

Tags: python-3.x

I am using python3 and I have a time data format like '01-FEB-17' and I need to parse it with `datetime.strptime`. Does anyone know which format is the correct for this? I tried `'%d-%b-%Y'`, `'%d-%m-%Y'`,... and none of them worked.

Thanks

Comment: You could look at [this](http://strftime.org/) site for format specifiers to use.

Comment: Try lower case `y` for 2 digit year: `%d-%b-%y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
from datetime import datetime
t = datetime.strptime('01-FEB-17', '%d-%b-%y')
```

**NOTE**: You can head [here](http://strftime.org/) for a full list of format specifiers to use

Comment: Worked like a charm. And thank you for pointing to the full list of formats.